# Nant build error: error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Localization' does not exist

Tags: dll, .net-4.0, nant

I have a decent size Nant build file (8 projects) where projects depend on eachother and so on, and everything works fine.  But I went to add in a new project (first in the build order), it compiles fine and the dll shows up, but when I go to reference it in another, I get the error:

> error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Localization' does not exist in
>   the namespace 'XXX' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)

Now in that csc command, I clearly have

```
<include name="./bin/XXX.Localization.dll"/>
```

I have checked the directory and it is there, I am very confused as to what is happening.  In this project, I also have a bunch of references to other dlls in the same directory that work fine.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Since the project had no .cs files in it, it didn't work right (only resx files).  I simply added in a dummy class and it worked fine...? Nant is the devil.

Comment: I have the same problem, my resources are all publics..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the project had no .cs files in it, it didn't work right (only resx files). I simply added in a dummy class and it worked fine.